# SQL Server: hierarchy implementation for records in the same table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, constraints, hierarchical-data

I've created a table named `sections`. Its structure is as below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sections]
(
    [_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [title] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [section_level] [int] NOT NULL,
    [parent_section] [int] NOT NULL,
    [order_in_parent_section] [int] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_sections] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([_id] ASC)
           WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
                 IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
                 ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I'm going to relate each section to other section (like a hierarchical tree). For this purpose I've used `parent_section` filed which is going to hold parent id of current record. I don't know how to implement this constraint?

Besides, after such an implementation, I was wondering how I can delete all rows in this table if necessary? Should I run multiple queries and first delete leaf nodes, then iterate this process till no node remain or there are some other known efficient methods?

Comment: Take a look at [`hierarchyid`'s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), I have no EXP with them but I think they might suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on the record as loving the hierarchyid datatype. I like using it with the type of setup that you already have, which is to say with an explicit ID and a foreign key pointing to the immediate parent.

To answer your question about how to implement the foreign key, you can create a self-referential foreign key.

```
alter table [dbo].[sections]
   add constraint [FK_sections_parent]
   foreign key (parent_id)
   references [dbo].[sections] (_id);
```

This assumes that whatever record is at the top of the hierarchy has a null value for its parentid.

Now, for the hierarchyid bit. Assuming that you add a column called "path" to your table of type hierarchyid, you can populate it with something like the following:

```
with cte as (
   select [_id], [parent_id], 
      '/' as [path]
   from [dbo].[sections]
   where [parent_id] is null

   union all

   select c.[_id], c.[parent_id], 
      p.[path] + cast([_id] as varchar(50)) + '/' as [path]
   from [dbo].[sections] as c
   join cte as p
      on c.[parent_id] = p.[_id]
)

update s
set [path] = cte.[path]
from [dbo].[sections] as s
join cte
   on s.[_id] = p.[_id];
```

Lastly, if you really need to delete all the data out of the table, dropping the foreign key and truncating the table is probably the most efficient. If that's no an option, you can use the `GetLevel()` method on the hierarchyid to find the deepest records, delete those, and then do it (i.e. find and delete the next deepest) again until you've deleted all the records.